# How to get details of two tables using order by date in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named as wsbill and wspay. wsbill used to store billing details and wspay used to store payment details. i want to viw transaction details of these two tables.

Structure of my table is,

```
 mysql> select * from wspay;
 +------------+-------+------+
 | WDATE      | NAME  | AMT  |
 +------------+-------+------+
 | 2015-01-28 | Bilal | 2000 |
 | 2015-01-30 | Bilal | 5000 |
 +------------+-------+------+

  mysql> select * from wsbill;
  +------------+---------+-------+------+--------+-------+
  | WDATE      | WSELLER | BILL  | LESS | REASON | FAMT  |
  +------------+---------+-------+------+--------+-------+
  | 2015-01-27 | Bilal   | 11000 | 1000 | test   | 10000 |
  | 2015-01-29 | Bilal   | 12000 | 1000 | test   | 11000 |
  +------------+---------+-------+------+--------+-------+
```

Now i want output like,

```
  2015-01-27  Bilal    11000  1000  test    10000
  2015-01-28  Bilal  2000 
  2015-01-29  Bilal    12000  1000  test    11000
  2015-01-30  Bilal  5000
```

which means order by date. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from (
     select wdate, name, amt, null as less, null as reason, null as famt
     from wspay
     union
     select wdate, wseller, bill, less, reason, famt
     from wsbill
     ) x
order by wdate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT * from ( select * from table1
   union
   select * from table2 )order by WDATE DESC
```

Comment: A union won't work if the tables have different numbers of columns.